# Token EndElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization, datacontractserializer, isolatedstoragefile

I am developing an application for wp7.i am storing the state of my application in isolatedstoragefile using datacontractserializer.Now when i try to serialize the object
sometimes i face this exception.

> Token EndElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid
>   XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to
>   ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to
>   write an XML fragment.

here is my class which i am serializing

```
[DataContract]
public class TcpSessionProperties
{
  [DataMember]
    public int NumberOfReceivedStanzas { get { return _numberOfReceivedStanzas; } set { _numberOfReceivedStanzas = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public int NumberOfPacketsSent { get { return _numberOfPacketsSent; } set { _numberOfPacketsSent = value; } }


    [DataMember]
    public List<TcpPacket> PendingPacketsToSendQueue
    {
        get { return _pendinPacketsToSendQueue; }
        set
        {
            LogUtility.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
            _pendinPacketsToSendQueue = value;
        }
    }

}

cla
```

Here is my code where i am serializing and deserializing

```
public class AppCacheIsolatedFile
{
    public static void Add(object val)
    {
      private static object _objectToSave;

        lock (_storageLock)
        {
            /*
            if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey(key))
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[key] = val;
            else
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add(key, val);
             */
            _objectToSave = val;
            WriteObject(NameOfFile, val, typeof(StreamingSocketConnection.StreamingSocketConnection));
        }
         public static void WriteObject(string fileName,object val,Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
            "Creating a Person object and serializing it.");

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, IsoStore))
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(type);
                dcs.WriteObject(stream, val);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            LogUtility.NotifyUserAndLog("Exception occured in isolatd storage file  while writing "+exception.StackTrace); 
        }


    }


    }
```

That exception occurs at dcs.writeobject. I donnot why is this happening.

Comment: This seems really strange. Try writing to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead, and see if you get the same error. If so, look at what has been written to the stream.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot I checked it using IsolatedStorageTool What i found  was that xml file ,which it was generating ,contained <packetsendingqueue>some xml</packetsendingque> some more xml which should  have been inside </packetsendingqueue>.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that there are more than one thread involved, and they are slightly out of sync. One completes and writes the end-tag, but the other isn't quite finished yet.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot But i have taken lock before writing it.

Comment: Just a guess; I don't know. You will have to debug it some more, trying to catch when the end-element is written.